# How do I get the touchscreen pointer driver working on a Panasonic CF-19 Toughbook?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, touchscreen

The only [instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CF-19) I have managed to find in google are related to Ubuntu 8.04 - While mine is 11.10. Have anyone managed to get it solved out?

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CF-19

Comment: can you add the link to what information you have found?

Comment: @fossfreedom link added in question body. thanks for the comment.

Comment: What does lsusb reports? Is it listed on the http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html ? If not, see http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html

Comment: @int_ua i'll check and post back the results. thanks for the tip

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!